# How to use 'LIKE' statement with unicode strings?

Tags: sql, unicode, sql-server-2005, sql-like

I am trying to execute a query with unicode characters. I was able to execute the normal equality query by prepending `N` to the query (Eg: `..... WHERE column=N'exact_stringâ'`). But that doesn't seem to work when I try to use `LIKE`. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Sample query:
`SELECT * FROM t_sample WHERE t_column LIKE N'%â%'`

Also how can I know which encoding does the SQL Server use to store the `nvarchar` or `nchar` data type and what encoding it uses to show the query in SQL Editor?

EDIT: My bad. This actually works. I have tried executing the query in a wrong window. But the upside of this is that I learned about Collation settings in SQL Server.

Comment: depends on your collation setting

Comment: Thanks Mitch. Where can I check that setting for the current instance?

Comment: Your collation is per column, per table, per database (using inheritance unless otherwise specified). If you do a `sp_help` you should see what the collation on the columns is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the collation on your table supports unicode.

Comment: _ALL_ collations support Unicode in SQL Server. Unicode vs non-Unicode is simply a matter of datatype (`VARCHAR` = non-Unicode, except starting in SQL Server 2019 when it can now be Unicode via UTF-8, and `NVARCHAR` = Unicode via UTF-16). There are some collations that are Unicode-_only_ and have no 8-bit code page support (and thus do not work with `VARCHAR`), but everything works with `NVARCHAR`.

Answer (score 29):

Use a Unicode search string:

```
WHERE CONTRACTORNAME LIKE N'%ạ%'
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365385/75500)

Comment: Use this way: `WHERE CONTRACTORNAME LIKE N'%yourstring%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2`

Comment: Short and nice. This should have been accepted answer

Comment: this one flies for me too

Comment: Althought it's a nice answer, it does not work for all unicode characters. For instance (using SSMS), this does not work : 
`WHERE CONTRACTORNAME LIKE N'%' ` 
while this does work
`WHERE SUBSTRING(CONTRACTORNAME, 1, 1) = N''`