# SQL LIKE statement using using unicode characters does not show correct result

Tags: unicode, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm just wondering why this statement doesn't work correctly.

For example: The statement

```
WHERE CONTRACTORNAME LIKE '%á%'
```

would gives me the correct result for every records containing "á". But the statement

```
WHERE CONTRACTORNAME LIKE '%ạ%'
```

would not gives any records even though in `CONTRACTORNAME` column have a tons of records containing this character. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251765/how-to-use-like-statement-with-unicode-strings

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2. Just edited my question :D

Answer (score 17):

Try using a Unicode search string:

```
WHERE CONTRACTORNAME LIKE N'%ạ%'
```